# PDF Form Filling with Multiple Data

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I have got all value from database in $data variable, And I tried to fill all data in fillable print. But the problem is if there are 5 different data then PDF should have multiple pages with a fillable PDF print. I need multiple data in a single pdf document.

Right now the code is filling last value in PDF form. I need to create a new page in PDF with that editable form.

```
$data = [
            'app_no'    => $bid_num,
            'unique_no'    => $unique,
            'unique_no2'    => $unique,
            'cut_off'    => 'CUT OFF',
            'cut_off2'    => 'CUT OFF',
            'name1' => $client_name,
            'name2'    => $client_name2,
            'address1'   => $client_address,
            'branch_code'   => $branch_code,
            'area'   => $client_area,
            'city'   => $client_city,
            'pin'   => $k->client_pin,
            'email'   => $client_email,
            'phone'   => $client_contact,
            'pan'   => $k->client_pan,
            'pan2'   => $k->client_pan,
            'pan3'   => $k->client_pan,
            'client_id1' => $client_id,
            'client_id3' => $client_id,
            'NSDL'    => $nsdl,
            'CDSL'   => $cdsl,
            'personal'   => $person,
            'huf'    => $huf,
            'other'    => $other,
            'date'   => $date,
            'bank_name2'    => $bank_name.', '.$bank_city,
            'bank_acco_no1' => $client_account_no,
            'amount_block2'    => $total,
            'client_id2'   => $client_id,
            'app_no2'   => $bid_num,
            'bank_no3'    => $client_account_no,
            'bank_name' => $bank_name.', '.$bank_city,
            'amount_words'    => $total_words,
            'amount_blocked'   => $total,
            'share'   => $share,
            'Retail'   => '<</T(Retail)/V(Yes)>>',
            'amount_block3'    => $total,
            'share2' => $share,
            'email2'    => $client_email,
            'phone2'   => $client_contact,
            'client_name'   => $k->client_name,
            'app_no3'    => $bid_num,
            'bank_name3' => $bank_name.', '.$bank_city,
            'bank_name4' => $bank_name.', '.$k->bank_city,
            'bank_acco_no2'   => $client_account_no,
            'name3'   => $k->client_name
        ];

        $pdf = new PdfForm($pdf, $data); // $pdf is pdf name which is fillable PDF

        $pdf->flatten()
            ->save('output.pdf')
            ->download();
        }
```

Look once and please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to var_dump your $data variable.It looks from your code like an array with multiple values not multiple arrays with multiple values.You shuld have something like this $data = array [0 => array [...al your valuyes here],1=> array[...all your values here] ] and so on.

Comment: can you please give an example?